# Should I accept an opinion-based answer if an objective one doesn't appear to be forthcoming?

Tags: discussion, answers, citations, accepted-answer

I asked [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/174144/13529) about the limitations of the Pathfinder spell *stone shape*, which are not well-defined in the game system. I was looking for either an explicit rule that I missed, an evidence-based interpretation such as examples of other spells that could set a precedent, or a relevant citation from an authoritative source like the FAQ or a Paizo designer's tweet/forum post. I don't consider this to be a subjective question because such an answer could theoretically be found - however, it seems that one does not actually exist at the moment.

The only current answer to my question is a reasonable interpretation of the spell, but it is still just one individual's interpretation. It contains no new information and the rationale is somewhat tenuous, as noted in the comments. Should I leave the question unanswered because there is still no conclusive answer or should I accept the existing answer as the best available interpretation until a better one comes along?

Answer (score 21):

## Only accept answers that answer the question

The "mark as answer" option is yours to do as you wish. Therefore you can choose to use it on any answer you choose. There is no right or wrong way to use it.

However, if you don't feel the current answer fully satisfies your question marking it as an answer makes it less likely that you will receive additional answers. This is the same reason you see recommendations not to mark an answer within 24 hours. While there is nothing to prevent you from moving your answer mark later there is some truth to the idea that having a marked answer makes new answers less likely.

If you are unsatisfied with the available answers and want to draw more attention you can always start a bounty to get more eyes on the question while explaining what you find lacking the current answers.